# Angular4 - let multiple unrelated components notify each other of the problem of updating data, and whether there is a cleaner coding method?

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I have encountered a project in progress, let multiple unrelated components notify each other of the update data, is there a cleaner coding method?

There are 3 components (more likely later) and a common-data component. They have no parent-child relationship with each other and only show on the same screen.

The desired effect is to press the button of any component, update the contents of common-data, and notify yourself and other components to fetch new messages from common-data.

At present, my approach is to use Rx's Observable and Subscription, but they must be imported in the component.ts and service.ts files of each component, and a lot of duplicate code appears, it is very messy, I don't know what is better. practice?

Thanks!

My code :
The sample name is test-a-comp (a.b.c and so on, the code is the same)

test-a-comp.html

```
<p>
{{ownMessage}}
</p>
<button (click)="sendChange()">update</button>
```

test-a-comp.component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription';
import { CommonData } from '../common-data/common-data';
import { TestACompService } from './test-a-comp.service';
import { TestBCompService } from '../test-b-comp/test-b-comp.service';
import { TestCCompService } from '../test-c-comp/test-c-comp.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-test-a-comp',
  templateUrl: './test-a-comp.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./test-a-comp.component.css']
})
export class TestACompComponent implements OnInit {

  subscription: Subscription;
  ownMessage;

  constructor(
    private testAService: TestACompService,
    private testBService: TestBCompService,
    private testCService: TestCCompService,
  ) {
    this.subscription = this.testAService.getMessage()
      .subscribe((test) => {
        CommonData.message = test;
      });
    this.subscription = this.testBService.getMessage()
      .subscribe(() => {
        this.ownMessage = CommonData.message;
      });
    this.subscription = this.testCService.getMessage()
      .subscribe(() => {
        this.ownMessage = CommonData.message;
      });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  sendChange() {
    this.testAService.sendMessage();
  }

}
```

test-a-comp.service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {Subject} from 'rxjs/Subject';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import {Subscription} from 'rxjs/Subscription';

@Injectable()
export class TestACompService {
  subscription: Subscription;

  private subject = new Subject<any>();

  constructor() {
  }

  getMessage(): Observable<any> {
    return this.subject.asObservable();
  }

  sendMessage(): void {
    this.subject.next('update message from A');
  }

}
```

Comment: Why don't you create a common service for all these components?

Comment: Try @ngrx/store it's a state management system based on rxjs and is a cool thing to populate some state across the app

Answer (score 0):

As far as i understand & you've mentioned in the above, there is a button in one of the component (test-a-component.html). If you update the button, you need to send message to other components which are subscribed.

The Components which have no Parent-Child relationship can communicate via a service:

1. Create a single service file (In your case: test-a-comp.service)
2. Create a Subject on what data you need to communicate via this service:

   ```
      export class testMessageService {

          constructor() {}

          // Observable string sources
       private message = new Subject<string>();

       //Observable string streams
       testMessage$ = this.message.asObservable();

       constructor() {}

       // Method to send message when a button is clicked
       sendMessage(message: string) {
          this.message.next(message);
       }

       /* You don't need "getMessage()" method as you've already subscribed to 
          the observables. There subscribed Observable string streams are 
          injected in your components (As below point 3) to display / do other 
          operation on the message.  */


      }
   ```
3. In your other Components, where you want to receive messages, do the following:

   ```
        export class TestComponent 1 {
           myMessage1: string;

           constructor(private TestMessageService: testMessageService) {}
             TestMessageService.testMessage$.subscribe(message => {
                this.myMessage1 = message;               

             });
        }

        export class TestComponent 2 {
           myMessage2: string;

           constructor(private TestMessageService: testMessageService) {}
             TestMessageService.testMessage$.subscribe(message => {
                this.myMessage2 = message;               

             });
        }

        export class TestComponent 3 {
           myMessage3: string;

           constructor(private TestMessageService: testMessageService) {}
             TestMessageService.testMessage$.subscribe(message => {
                this.myMessage3 = message;               

             });
        }
   ```

   **For more information/guidance refer Component interaction via a common 
    service: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction**

### Hope this helps!